# Possible to remove a member from a BIM360 Project via Forge?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

Is it possible to remove a member from a Autodesk BIM360 Docs Project? I understand how to add a member via POST and / or change member characteristics via PATCH but am not clear whether it's possible to remove a project member.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Here's the [API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/users-:user_id-PATCH/)

Comment: Thank you for your response Varun.  I believe the API link you provided is to perform a PATCH for the user at the account level.  Here you can change a user's status but this would be global for their account on the hub.  I was interested in knowing whether I can remove them from a particular project via Forge.

Comment: Unfortunately, the project-level support is unavailable at this moment, and we have logged a wish list item to support this feature as `ACSADMIN-1655`. We apologize for the inconvenience had caused.

Comment: @EasonKang if I got it right, there is no appropriate endpoint still?